# Execute an order by edittext in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

plzzz 
How the user can select the cosinus or log or .... by edittext in android studio ????

```
        y =  Math.cos(x);   <<== //how to selct cos(x) by edittext
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h45L0.png)

Comment: Hi ayoub! You would get more/faster/better answers if you edit your question so that it is clear what you have tried, what your set-up is and so on. See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance, especially the part about a minimal example :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand you well, but for selection you won't need EditText , you need something like [Spinners](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner) this would help you in multiple selections, i hope that answers your question if not please provide more information to be able to help you.

Comment: I want the user to write cos(X) Then press on button

Comment: maybe you can use spinner for all the possible solutions and button next to it, he selects what matches the photo then clicks on the button, see the documentation for spinners for more info about it

Comment: no plzz I want it by edittext Because there are too many possibilities